# Perspective correction of imageview

Tags: android, image-processing

I'm working on an app that needs to apply perspective distortion correction to a photo taken with the phone's camera.
Once the photo is taken, the idea is to show it on an imageview and let the user mark the four corners of the document (a card, a sheet of paper, etc.) and then apply the correction based on those points.
This is an example of what im trying to achieve:

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ro9hniPj52E/TkoM0kTlEnI/AAAAAAAAAbQ/c2R5VrgmC_w/s640/s4.jpg

Any ideas on how to do this on **android**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do goes under various names of art, "corner-pin" being the one commonly used in the visual effects industry. You need to proceed in two steps:

1. Compute the mapping from the the desired, rectified image, to the original, distorted, image
2. Actually warp the original image according to the mapping computed in (1).

The 4 (non-collinear, perspective-distorted) corners of the original image, and the 4 corners of the target (undistorted) image, define the mapping. This mapping is called a "[homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography)" - read the pointed wikipedia page for details. Once the mapping is known, the warping at step (2) can be computed by interpolation: for every pixel in the target image, find the corresponding pixel in the original image. As this will typically not be at integer coordinates, you interpolate its color from the neighbors. Various interpolation schemes are used, the common ones being nearest-neighbor, bilinear and bicubic (in increasing order of smoothness in the results).

For Android, I'd recommend installing the [OpenCV SDK](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android) , and then use the [geometry transformation routines](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html) (getPerspectiveTransform and warpPerspective for the two steps above).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I will try with OpenCV.

Answer (score 13):

You **don't have to** use a **library** for this.
You can just as well use one of the `drawBitmap` functions of the `Canvas` class with a matrix that's initialized using the `setPolyToPoly` function of the `Matrix` class.

```
public static Bitmap cornerPin(Bitmap b, float[] srcPoints, float[] dstPoints) {
    int w = b.getWidth(), h = b.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(result);
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.setPolyToPoly(srcPoints, 0, dstPoints, 0, 4);
    c.drawBitmap(b, m, p);
    return result;
}
```

(*The Paint object is only needed to enable anti-aliasing.*)

Usage:

```
int w = bitmap.getWidth(), h = bitmap.getHeight();
float[] src = {
    0, 0, // Coordinate of top left point
    0, h, // Coordinate of bottom left point 
    w, h, // Coordinate of bottom right point
    w, 0  // Coordinate of top right point
};
float[] dst = {
    0, 0,        // Desired coordinate of top left point 
    0, h,        // Desired coordinate of bottom left point  
    w, 0.8f * h, // Desired coordinate of bottom right point
    w, 0.2f * h  // Desired coordinate of top right point
};
Bitmap transformed = cornerPin(bitmap, src, dst);
```

Where `src` are the coordinates of the source points, `dst` are the coordinates of the destination points. Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ Attila Tanyi  , As per your example left edge is fix and right is moving i want right edge should fix and move left edge and similarly for top and bottom. What should i do ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: @GyanSwaroopAwasthi - I edited my answer, the numbers should make more sense now. You should change the `dst` float array in the example. If it has exactly the same numbers as the `src` array, then the bitmap stays the same. Other than that, you just need to change the coordinate of the point that you need to move. The coordinates are (x, y) pairs, where x is the column (from left to right), and y is the row (from top to bottom).